# How to do a binary compare of multiple folders?

Tags: windows

I have >100 folders that I would like to compare. I don't want to merge, but simply make sure that the content of those folders are the same. How can I do this on Windows and without Beyond Compare?

Comment: Which version of windows?

Comment: Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: Why not Beyond Compare? Just the cost or is it not working how you would like it to?

Comment: Yep, I use Beyond Compare for this sort of stuff.  Or write a "quick and dirty" Java program.

Comment: Beyond Compare for more than 100 folders doesn't really scale.

Answer (score 7):

I usually use [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) to compare trees. You can obviously use it to do some merging, but you don't have to. And it's free.

Answer (score 1):

Any good Unix-style cmp binary compare utility with a recursive option will do what you want.  Not sure if Cygwin's cmp will do that but the cmp I include with my Hamilton C shell certainly will.  Full disclosure:  I'm the author.